# Matlab - candlestick plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I made a candlestick plot with long and short trades. Longs are in green, shorts are in red. 
The plot was generated using:

```
 hold on
candle( H(long_range), L(long_range), C(long_range), O(long_range), 'g');
candle( H(short_range), L(short_range), C(short_range), O(short_range), 'r');
```

long_range is like [1,2,3,4,5, 10,11,12,13,14,15,..]

short_range is like [6,7,8,9, 16,...]

I would like to have a single plot, with candlesticks with long trades colored in green, and  candlesticks with short trades colored in red. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking about `hold`? Read `help hold` and see if that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: A somewhat related discussion: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1177-plotting-a-normal-graph-with-a-candlestick-graph